# How to change OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I want to change the `OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE` parameter in a local installation of Oracle 9i (32bit 9.2.0.1.0 Enterprise Edition running on Windows Server 2003) in an attempt to reproduce a performance issue reported by a client but I can't figure out how to do it. Both `ALTER SESSION` and `ALTER SYSTEM` statements trigger this error (even if run as SYS):

> ORA-02095: specified initialization
>   parameter cannot be modified

How can I change it?

**Update:**

The steps I followed (thanks to [Gary's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/276340/how-to-change-optimizer-features-enable-in-oracle-9i/276504#276504)) were this:

1. Create an empty file: `C:\oracle\ora92\DBS\INIT.ORA`
2. Edit the file to add: `optimizer_features_enabled = 8.1.7`
3. Launch Windows service manager
4. Restart the service called `OracleServiceFOO`, where FOO is my instance name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [static parameter](http://www.oracleracexpert.com/2009/09/how-to-change-static-parameters-in.html) so it needs to be changed in the pfile / spfile and then the instance restarted.

Comment: Thank you. The article omits many things but it helped me to figure out the necessary steps. I've updated the question to reflect them.